# Choosing Java web framework for project?

Tags: java, geomajas, framework

We are developing java web gis application.

We use geoserver, postgis, geotools(all the core code).

We need to show/hide(or create/delete) **dynamically** vector layers(from shape file) and raster layers(wms layer from geoserver).
Also, our shapefiles are colorized(there are about 5-10 colorized zones in one shapefile).

Typical usage: user check/uncheck checkboxes -> layers are showed/hid.

We used geomajas in our 0 version, but there is the critical bug for us( http://jira.geomajas.org/browse/RTC-2 ).

So, could you please suggest any other java based web frameworks that can cover our needs?

Comment: could you elaborate on why GeoTools isn't working? It sounds like UDig can do every thing you need out of the box.

Comment: does geotools provide web framework to render vector/raster layers? Geotools works good for us doing all the core code.

Comment: You might want to answer your own question and accept it. That way, people will know that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We moved to grails + OpenLayers. Works great, much more easier than geomajas, no strict relation with gwt, it satisfied all our needs(ajaxian show of vector/raster layers, flexibility).

Answer (score 4):

Java + Vaadin + vol (vOpenlayers) works smooth. If you are looking for a 'new' framework, but I would stick with your current solution and work from there and contribute to the community...

Answer (score 3):

You could wwork with the Geomajas community to fix the problem. Just complaining that something does not work will not get things fixed. In many open source projects, the community is a volunteer effort. The very least you have to do is give a good explanation of your needs and problem. Fastest way to a solution is to dive into the code and try to fix. You may even learn something in the process. Most communities are quite willing to answer (technical) questions while you are learning how the project operates.

Comment: Hi Joachim, we developed another part of our application, so it wasn`t so critically for us. But the month has passed, no comments from the geomajas community. We debugged the code. It seems that on the geomajas side all the beans are prepared properly. But spring can`t create the beans and throws org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException (the same as in the attached stacktrace). Any thoughts how can we fix it?

Comment: Best approach is to build a test which reproduces the problem. That would be needed to fix and prevent regressions anyway.
Also best to use majas-dev for communications, I am not sure whether all developers follow JIRA changes.

Comment: Do you have any news about the issue? We attached the test and shp file to jira. Any road map for the bug? Because right now we will be going to openlayers if the bug can`t be fixed in a week or two.

Comment: Please ask on majas-dev. I have not worked on the runtimeconfig module myself and I don't know whether the other developers follow stackexchange and/or all changes in the Geomajas JIRA.